# Separate Document vs Map/Reduce

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

Given the following entities

```
public class Device
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IList<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

I need to query devices by id. Device id is unique. A device belongs always to one user.

Should I store devices as separate documents as well or is a map reduce function over users "okay"? I need to access a particular device very often (there may be cache in between but still)?

Any hints or suggestions or best-practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the devices as separate documents in their own collection, you wouldn't really need to query at all since you know their IDs. You could just use the Load method which should be faster.

If you do store them as separate documents, you need to think about consistency on deletes and updates, e.g. if a device is deleted you need to make sure you also find all the users that had this device and delete the references.

It doesn't make sense to make a map-reduce index over users. Think of the reduce function as a group by on the output of the map function. The shape of the output of the map function and the reduce function must also be the same. What would you group users by to get an index of devices?

But on the other hand, if you store them only on the users, you could create a field for device IDs in a users index, and then query for the user(s) that have a specific device ID, and pick up the device from the user document.

```
public class UsersIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<User>
{
    public UsersIndex()
    {
        Map = docs=> from doc in docs
                     select new 
                     { 
                         DeviceIds = doc.Devices.Select(x => x.Id)
                     };
    }
}

var device = DbSession.Advanced.LuceneQuery<User, UsersIndex>()
                      .WhereEquals("DeviceIds", 123)
                      .Select(x => x.Devices.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == 123));
```